# Unite two similar routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this two routes:

```
  get "shopping", to: "bar#show"
  get "shopping/*relative_path", to: "bar#show"
```

**How can I join them, to one route?**

When I simply omit `get "shopping", to: "bar#show"` then the user who goes to `localhost:3000/shopping` is not redirected to the controller `bar#show`

**Thanks**

Comment: did you try to use only second route?

Comment: You could try `match '/:shopping(/*relative_path)', to: 'bar#show', via: :get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make second part optional by wrapping it into parenthesis:

```
get "shopping(/*relative_path)", to: "bar#show"
```

Description of this behavior in [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters).